# I was trying to implement naive namespaces and realized that i don't understand how recursion works

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tree

I wanted to implement naive namespaces so that I could do such queries:

- `create_namespace(namespace, parent)` — add new namespace to parent namespace
- `add_var(namespace, var)` — add new variable to namespace
- `get_var(namespace, var)` — return closest namespace where variable is contained

Eventually I managed to implement the first two of them so I can now create a tree-structure like this:

```
d = {'global':{'vars': {'a'},'local':{'foo': {'vars': set(), 'local': {'foo1': {'vars': {'a'}, 'local': {}}}}, 'bar': {'vars': set(), 'local': {'foo2': {'vars': set(), 'local': {}}}}, 'baz': {'vars': set(), 'local': {'foo3': {'vars': {'a'}, 'local': {'foobar': {'vars': set(), 'local': {}}}}}}}}}
```

To clarify:

`get_var("foobar", "a")` should return `"foo3"`

`get_var("foo2", "a")` should return `"global"`

But I got completely stuck while trying to understand how recursion works and why sometimes we **return recursive call** and sometimes **just call function within itself** (internet doesn't help because I'm fed up already with *fibonacci* and *factorial*).

This implementation doesn't work because as I said I just can't get why my return values get lost when callstack is unwinded:

```
def get_var(namespace, var):
    def go_deeper(dic, location=None):
        if dic == {} or location == namespace:
            return location
        for (name, ns) in dic.items(): #iterate over namespaces within parent namespace
            if var in ns["vars"]:      
                go_deeper(ns["local"], name) #if we found variable *var* we remember its location by passing it as an argument 
            else:
                go_deeper(ns["local"], location) #otherwise we keep using previous found *location*
    return go_deeper(d)
```

Comment: Please run a test case and show us what you expect. Perhaps it would be helpful if indicated why you need to modify namespaces.  Your code is fairly complex.   If you want to see what is happening with recursion the simplest and least glamorous way is to insert a few print statements.

Comment: `return` only returns one level. You don't assign that value to a variable or return it so that value gets lost. Even worse is that your callee doesn't know a value was found so it continues the `for` loop at every level until all parts are visited before it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function, as you said is 'I just can't get why my return values get lost when callstack is unwinded'. One of the crucial point with recursive function is being able to have the result, found deep in the calls, being 'transmitted' back to the original function call. This case was not trivial, unlike the factorials or fibonacci.
Actually, you were quite close :-)
The solution is to check, when going deeper in the 'tree', if the namespace you're looking for is indeed present, while keeping track of the closest parent which contained the variable. Then to manage to 'transmit' this closest parent's name up the stack.
You can do that as follows:

```
def get_var(namespace, var):
    def go_deeper(dic, location=None):
        if namespace in dic:  # the namespace has been found, return the 'location'
            if var in dic[namespace]['locals']:  # check that the namespace itself does not contain the car, who knows
                return namespace
            else:
                return location
        for (name, ns) in dic.items():
            if var in ns["vars"]:
                result = go_deeper(ns["local"], name)
                if result is not None:
                    return result  #  if the namespace was found deeper, return/transmit the result('location') along the call stack
            else:
                res = go_deeper(ns["local"], location)
                if result is not None:
                    return result  # idem
        # return None  (the default behavior of a python function)
    return go_deeper(d)
```

Small advice: as it stands, the `dict` is very hard to read for a human. There is a small utility in the standard python lib called [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html) which allows for nice indented printing of nested data structures. I could understand the underlying structure of `d` only when I saw it like that:

```
pprint.pprint(d)
{'global': {'local': {'bar': {'local': {'foo2': {'local': {}, 'vars': set()}},
                              'vars': set()},
                      'baz': {'local': {'foo3': {'local': {'foobar': {'local': {},
                                                                      'vars': set()}},
                                                 'vars': {'a'}}},
                              'vars': set()},
                      'foo': {'local': {'foo1': {'local': {}, 'vars': {'a'}}},
                              'vars': set()}},
            'vars': {'a'}}}
```

Comment: Wow, that helped a lot. I fixed a couple typos and also it seems like the condition `if result is not None: …` is redundant so I decided to place it after else-clause inside the for-loop and it worked just perfectly. Because I already started thinking about giving up programming after third day of not solving this problem.

Comment: Nope, don't give up now :-) struggling is part of what makes programming fun even if it can be infuriating, I could never have written such a program a few years back, and I had my share of desperating 'unsolvable' problems. About the `if result is not None:` condition, I think it is needed, to prevent the program from not looping on all the subspaces available. For instance if the namespace is in the second child namespace of the loop, we need to call `go_deeper` on it as well (I'm not certain though). Try testing it more extensively (and don't give up ^^)

Answer (score 0):

I propose another solution, with 2 different recursive functions.

```
def get_var(search_namespace, var, dict):
    for dict_namespace, sub_dict in dict.items():
        vars = sub_dict['vars']
        locals = sub_dict['local']

        # recursively search search_namespace in locals
        found_namespace = get_var(search_namespace, var, locals)
        if found_namespace is not None:
            return found_namespace
        # search if current namespace is a solution
        if var in vars and dict_contains(search_namespace, locals):
            return dict_namespace

    return None

def dict_contains(searched_key, dictionary):
    if not isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        return False
    return any(key==searched_key or dict_contains(searched_key, value)
                for key, value in dictionary.items())
```